# Hash256 in Java and PHP doesn't return the same result

Tags: java, php, hash, sha256

I have a Java code that `hash` several array of bytes.
I'm trying to convert this code to PHP, but whatever I try my final hash is different.

The Java code (provided by a third party):

```java
MessageDigest digest;
digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

byte[] digestBytes;
byte[] cM = [158,116,27,162,197,2,176,250,41,54,95,61,64,126,102,222,103,190,2,233,223,230,66,131,120,10,248,199,46,248,52,93,6,150,121,132,8,130,72,224,26,125,85,240,16,99,15,14,182,187,225,48,35,9,1,250,126,173,94,187,85,83,106,148,233,105,219,101,177,250,66,218,224,193,114,144,59,211,64,206,49,183,111,58,156,200,175,190,254,219,148,71,116,1,77,181,127,46,223,248,51,166,64,61,227,161,7,167,116,113,177,156,139,178,88,89,232,57,58,196,67,97,42,5,114,134,147,199,157,233,186,49,196,20,145,191,52,212,179,162,160,17,215,82,153,4,226,25,212,250,213,111,42,134,227,198,246,110,157,201,39,222,232,196,120,12,203,189,77,211,79,110,197,227,190,4,145,90,203,178,157,206,255,242,142,37,104,239,138,234,56,252,173,98,58,152,141,242,130,136,77,248,248,189,235,144,231,136,137,167,80,172,43,38,77,109,22,81,191,61,90,23,59,220,48,144,104,229,162,186,31,173,52,97,176,35,213,7,217,224,156,163,185,249,96,197,69,50,47,45,64,95,101,133,187,223];
byte[] cE = [1,0,1];
byte[] sM = [222,65,253,234,66,194,53,104,75,194,217,168,58,72,163,25,120,109,184,190,188,201,5,57,43,52,147,209,222,49,169,181,211,202,157,206,153,184,61,225,148,175,51,48,175,149,3,67,142,183,123,160,222,251,88,151,14,101,191,156,195,248,188,73,50,228,59,105,248,117,240,131,204,178,16,159,144,98,148,96,32,195,79,8,62,221,31,249,221,241,249,13,70,148,188,1,173,175,204,24,68,249,246,163,194,77,72,50,185,15,115,253,203,14,249,173,65,219,5,25,71,83,32,242,52,200,97,171,160,47,42,188,190,169,216,207,33,83,97,230,111,188,51,75,129,217,25,16,168,34,73,219,214,0,225,106,40,41,237,22,119,231,246,117,179,53,202,36,163,118,22,79,114,67,66,221,93,58,241,23,123,28,239,199,124,183,78,55,243,137,246,0,72,196,40,128,65,252,78,19,52,41,183,84,34,123,173,63,88,128,200,132,123,182,255,98,167,235,106,176,222,129,210,232,145,136,75,68,152,192,177,253,115,57,115,65,116,175,46,174,115,191,105,218,254,105,182,213,70,47,53,219,32,233,104,255];
byte[] sE = [1,0,1];
byte[] nonce = [38,166];

digest.update(cM);
digest.update(cE);
digest.update(sM);
digest.update(sE);
digest.update(nonce);

digestBytes = digest.digest();
// I've been told the result should be : [38,126,166,123,158,41,83,110,160,92,148,34,0,235,126,62,88,10,13,229,0,141,125,7,84,155,11,90,107,52,188,217]
```

In PHP I tried dozens of things, but without success… See below one of the MANY MANY things I tried:

```php
$cM = [158,116,27,162,197,2,176,250,41,54,95,61,64,126,102,222,103,190,2,233,223,230,66,131,120,10,248,199,46,248,52,93,6,150,121,132,8,130,72,224,26,125,85,240,16,99,15,14,182,187,225,48,35,9,1,250,126,173,94,187,85,83,106,148,233,105,219,101,177,250,66,218,224,193,114,144,59,211,64,206,49,183,111,58,156,200,175,190,254,219,148,71,116,1,77,181,127,46,223,248,51,166,64,61,227,161,7,167,116,113,177,156,139,178,88,89,232,57,58,196,67,97,42,5,114,134,147,199,157,233,186,49,196,20,145,191,52,212,179,162,160,17,215,82,153,4,226,25,212,250,213,111,42,134,227,198,246,110,157,201,39,222,232,196,120,12,203,189,77,211,79,110,197,227,190,4,145,90,203,178,157,206,255,242,142,37,104,239,138,234,56,252,173,98,58,152,141,242,130,136,77,248,248,189,235,144,231,136,137,167,80,172,43,38,77,109,22,81,191,61,90,23,59,220,48,144,104,229,162,186,31,173,52,97,176,35,213,7,217,224,156,163,185,249,96,197,69,50,47,45,64,95,101,133,187,223];
$cE = [1,0,1];
$sM = [222,65,253,234,66,194,53,104,75,194,217,168,58,72,163,25,120,109,184,190,188,201,5,57,43,52,147,209,222,49,169,181,211,202,157,206,153,184,61,225,148,175,51,48,175,149,3,67,142,183,123,160,222,251,88,151,14,101,191,156,195,248,188,73,50,228,59,105,248,117,240,131,204,178,16,159,144,98,148,96,32,195,79,8,62,221,31,249,221,241,249,13,70,148,188,1,173,175,204,24,68,249,246,163,194,77,72,50,185,15,115,253,203,14,249,173,65,219,5,25,71,83,32,242,52,200,97,171,160,47,42,188,190,169,216,207,33,83,97,230,111,188,51,75,129,217,25,16,168,34,73,219,214,0,225,106,40,41,237,22,119,231,246,117,179,53,202,36,163,118,22,79,114,67,66,221,93,58,241,23,123,28,239,199,124,183,78,55,243,137,246,0,72,196,40,128,65,252,78,19,52,41,183,84,34,123,173,63,88,128,200,132,123,182,255,98,167,235,106,176,222,129,210,232,145,136,75,68,152,192,177,253,115,57,115,65,116,175,46,174,115,191,105,218,254,105,182,213,70,47,53,219,32,233,104,255];
$sE = [1,0,1];
$nonce = [38,166];

function toHex($arr) {
  $chars = array_map("chr", $arr);
  $bin = join($chars);
  $hex = bin2hex($bin);
  return $hex;
}

$ctxHash = hash_init('SHA256');
hash_update($ctxHash, toHex($cM));
hash_update($ctxHash, toHex($cE));
hash_update($ctxHash, toHex($sM));
hash_update($ctxHash, toHex($sE));
hash_update($ctxHash, toHex($nonce));
$res = hash_final($ctxHash);

echo "[ ";
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($res); $i+=2) {
  echo hexdec($res{$i}.$res{$i+1}).", ";
}
echo " ]\n";
// result is => [ 27, 76, 45, 80, 123, 219, 71, 18, 245, 165, 109, 66, 156, 179, 42, 235, 25, 102, 206, 61, 200, 187, 198, 9, 185, 69, 138, 34, 56, 108, 8, 33 ]
```

It's been 2 days and I'm not able to find how to get the same result… Your help would be appreciated.

Note: the above code is a simplified version – in real life my variables are a Hex string (e.g. `cM = "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"`)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result that your third party provided is wrong. I pasted your java code into an editor and adjusted it so that it compiles:

```
public class Sha256 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest digest;
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        byte[] digestBytes;
        byte[] cM = b(158,116,27,162,197,2,176,250,41,54,95,61,64,126,102,222,103,190,2,233,223,230,66,131,120,10,248,199,46,248,52,93,6,150,121,132,8,130,72,224,26,125,85,240,16,99,15,14,182,187,225,48,35,9,1,250,126,173,94,187,85,83,106,148,233,105,219,101,177,250,66,218,224,193,114,144,59,211,64,206,49,183,111,58,156,200,175,190,254,219,148,71,116,1,77,181,127,46,223,248,51,166,64,61,227,161,7,167,116,113,177,156,139,178,88,89,232,57,58,196,67,97,42,5,114,134,147,199,157,233,186,49,196,20,145,191,52,212,179,162,160,17,215,82,153,4,226,25,212,250,213,111,42,134,227,198,246,110,157,201,39,222,232,196,120,12,203,189,77,211,79,110,197,227,190,4,145,90,203,178,157,206,255,242,142,37,104,239,138,234,56,252,173,98,58,152,141,242,130,136,77,248,248,189,235,144,231,136,137,167,80,172,43,38,77,109,22,81,191,61,90,23,59,220,48,144,104,229,162,186,31,173,52,97,176,35,213,7,217,224,156,163,185,249,96,197,69,50,47,45,64,95,101,133,187,223);
        byte[] cE = b(1,0,1);
        byte[] sM = b(222,65,253,234,66,194,53,104,75,194,217,168,58,72,163,25,120,109,184,190,188,201,5,57,43,52,147,209,222,49,169,181,211,202,157,206,153,184,61,225,148,175,51,48,175,149,3,67,142,183,123,160,222,251,88,151,14,101,191,156,195,248,188,73,50,228,59,105,248,117,240,131,204,178,16,159,144,98,148,96,32,195,79,8,62,221,31,249,221,241,249,13,70,148,188,1,173,175,204,24,68,249,246,163,194,77,72,50,185,15,115,253,203,14,249,173,65,219,5,25,71,83,32,242,52,200,97,171,160,47,42,188,190,169,216,207,33,83,97,230,111,188,51,75,129,217,25,16,168,34,73,219,214,0,225,106,40,41,237,22,119,231,246,117,179,53,202,36,163,118,22,79,114,67,66,221,93,58,241,23,123,28,239,199,124,183,78,55,243,137,246,0,72,196,40,128,65,252,78,19,52,41,183,84,34,123,173,63,88,128,200,132,123,182,255,98,167,235,106,176,222,129,210,232,145,136,75,68,152,192,177,253,115,57,115,65,116,175,46,174,115,191,105,218,254,105,182,213,70,47,53,219,32,233,104,255);
        byte[] sE = b(1,0,1);
        byte[] nonce = b(38,166);

        digest.update(cM);
        digest.update(cE);
        digest.update(sM);
        digest.update(sE);
        digest.update(nonce);

        digestBytes = digest.digest();
        System.out.print("[ ");
        for (int i = 0; i < digestBytes.length; i++) {
            System.out.format("%d, ", digestBytes[i] & 0xff);
        }
        System.out.print(" ]\n");
    }

    private static byte[] b(int...val) {
        byte[] result = new byte[val.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            result[i] = (byte)(val[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And that code gives a result of

```
[ 41, 248, 162, 75, 169, 252, 1, 239, 12, 250, 213, 238, 138, 137, 56, 54, 159, 183, 66, 79, 90, 228, 191, 39, 193, 159, 173, 238, 239, 95, 194, 40,  ]
```

Now your PHP code has one problem: the conversion from the bytes into the string that `hash_update()` needs does an extra `bin2hex()` conversion that the java code does not do.

If I change your `toHex()` function into a `toBin()` function:

```
function toBin($arr) {
  $chars = array_map("chr", $arr);
  $bin = join($chars);
  return $bin;
}
```

and use that function in the `hash_update()` calls:

```
$ctxHash = hash_init('SHA256');
hash_update($ctxHash, toBin($cM));
hash_update($ctxHash, toBin($cE));
hash_update($ctxHash, toBin($sM));
hash_update($ctxHash, toBin($sE));
hash_update($ctxHash, toBin($nonce));
$res = hash_final($ctxHash);
```

then I get the following result:

```
[ 41, 248, 162, 75, 169, 252, 1, 239, 12, 250, 213, 238, 138, 137, 56, 54, 159, 183, 66, 79, 90, 228, 191, 39, 193, 159, 173, 238, 239, 95, 194, 40, ]
```

which matches nicely with the output from java...

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I'll check with the third party to see why his result is different.